# How can I fix these errors?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class EmployeeTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Employee e = new Employee ("Jordan",70000.00);
    Manager m = new Manager ("William Johnson",90000.00,"Computer Science");
    Executive ex = new Executive ("GPC",120000.00,"School");

    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println(m);
    System.out.println(ex);
  }
```

Here is my constructor:

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private double salary;

  public Employee(String name, double salary, int department) {
    setName(name);
    setSalary(salary);
  }
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public double getSalary() {
    return this.salary;
  }
  public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
  }
  public void getDetails() {
    System.out.println("Name:" + getName());
    System.out.println("Salary:" +getSalary());
  }
}
```

I am currently stumped with this assignment. I have all four of my classes implemented with Employee. Then Manager is inheriting from Employee while also having Executive inherit from Manager. When I go to compile it I get these 2 errors found:
What am I doing wrong?

```
File: C:\Users\Jordan\Downloads\EmployeeTest.java  [line: 6]
Error: constructor Employee in class Employee cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,double,int
  found: java.lang.String,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
File: C:\Users\Jordan\Downloads\Manager.java  [line: 9]
Error: constructor Employee in class Employee cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,double,int
  found: java.lang.String,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: `reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: Beside the 'int department' part. I guess you also want to use e.getDetails() void method to print instead of the System.out.println(e). You will get gibberish code (address reference of object) for that if there's no overriding of toString() method. Same goes to your manager and executive objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output clearly says

```
Error: constructor Employee in class Employee cannot be applied to given types;
    required: java.lang.String,double,int
    found: java.lang.String,double
```

So instead of calling `Employee e = new Employee ("Jordan",70000.00)` constructor you need to pass three arguments to it which are `String, Double` and `int`. For example,

```
Employee e = new Employee ("Jordan",70000.00, 1);   //I passed 1 as args for example it could be anything that you defined in your code.
```

**Edit**
There you go, you just posted your `Employee` class code which clearly shows you have created a constructor that takes three arguments `String name, double salary, int department` and it looks as if you completely forgot what you want to do with the third arguments `department` as I do not see it being used anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in one extra argument to your employee creation call like so:

```
Employee e = new Employee ("Jordan",70000.00,42);
```

You have defined the constructor as `String`, `double`, `int` so you have to supply all three.